# DBCC SHOWCONTIG returns 2 rows against certain tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbcc

When I am running DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('schema_name.table_name') WITH TABLERESULTS, ALL_INDEXES, NO_INFOMSGS in SQL Server 2016 it is returning 2 rows against certain tables

Example below:

```
ObjectName  ObjectId    IndexName   IndexId Level   Pages   Rows    MinimumRecordSize   MaximumRecordSize   AverageRecordSize   ForwardedRecords    Extents ExtentSwitches  AverageFreeBytes    AveragePageDensity  ScanDensity BestCount   ActualCount LogicalFragmentation    ExtentFragmentation

table1_ 1891549497  col_st_idx  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0
table_  1891549497  col_st_idx  1   0   1   10  553 641 593.6   0   1   0   2140    73.5606622189276    100 1   1   0   0
```

I am unable to understand the reason for this behavior as ideally it should return only 1 row,can someone provide anything on that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition 64bit SP2-CU3

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists testtblZ
go

--clustered
create table testtblZ(col char(900) default('aaaa') not null);
create clustered index idxtesttblZ on testtblZ(col);
go
insert into testtblZ(col)
values(newid());
go 10
DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('testtblZ') WITH TABLERESULTS, ALL_INDEXES, NO_INFOMSGS;
go


--columnstore
create clustered columnstore index idxtesttblz on testtblz with (drop_existing = on);
go
insert into testtblZ(col)
values(newid());
go 10
DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('testtblZ') WITH TABLERESULTS, ALL_INDEXES, NO_INFOMSGS;
go
```

Comment: Trying to understand this, are you saying that I am seeing this because of column store index. Just to add here the concerned table indeed has column store index. The command  is not returning any data on SQL 2014 for that table but is returning 2 rows on SQL 2016.

Comment: ..@kanishkabasak ... in the latest versions a clustered column store index consists of a columnstore part (the 0 rows in the dbcc command) and a rowstore part (rows 10). When rowstore gets enough rows (+1mil) then "rows" are moved to the columnstore. I am not sure if the rowstore part was available/implemented in SQL2014..columnstores were a bit restricted/tight in the earliest versions... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#clustered-columnstore-index

Comment: thanks for sharing that, if you do come across anything further pls do share.

Comment: I am seeing that in 2 different SQL 2016 envs one is returning 1 row against DBCC SHOWCONTIG and the other 2 rows against the same table. Why would this be happening? Both the servers are on SQL2016 SP2-CU2.

Comment: ..@kanishkabasak : you could generate a creation script of the table which returns 2 dbcc showcontig rows and create a new foo table on the environment which returns 1 row. Then execute dbcc showcontig('foo') and verify that only a single row is returned. You could try dbcc 2 times, once without any rows in the foo table and for the second time with a few rows in the foo table.

Comment: yes, with records it did return 2 rows. Something that I came across too was that, when I run the DBCC SHOW CONTIG in SQL 2014 against column store indexed tables, I get nothing, which may be due to restrictions that it has related to varchar,nvarchar data types. However, when I run the same in SQL Server 2016 I get 2 rows for the same table. The restriction should hold irrespective of the version, or anything was changed 2016 onwards?